# Swift - Getting the position of an Item in an array of arrays represented as an Int instead of item itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a list of stations broken out by genre and have placed them in an array of arrays as such: [[Genre], [Genre], [Genre]]. I index in with stations[indexPath.section[indexPath.row] and this accesses a single station. In didSelectItemAt I can then pass this station to a presented media view controller and play it for the user. However, I would like to implement a next button as well as a previous button so the user can switch stations within the media VC itself without returning to the collection view. I can't seem to find a way to represent the position of a station in the stations array as an Int which I can then use as the logic in my next/previous buttons as I've attempted to below. I have tried using flatMap to flatten the array out for simplicity, which is nicer so I can index in with just stations[indexPath.row], but that still doesn't solve my problem. I tried to use .enumerated() but I couldn't figure out how to successfully use the index it provides given I need to append the tuple it returns into an array. Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this? I'm thinking it may not be possible..

```
import AVKit
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class MediaCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

var stations = [[Station]]()

let mediaVC = MediaPlayerVC()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchRadioStation()

    collectionView.register(MediaCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MediaCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    collectionView.register(MediaCollectionSectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: MediaCollectionSectionReusableView.identifier)

    
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int { stations.count  }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return stations[section].count }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
        let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: MediaCollectionSectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionSectionReusableView
        
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            sectionHeader.label.text = "TV"
            return sectionHeader
        case 1:
            sectionHeader.label.text = "News Radio"
            return sectionHeader
        case 2:
            sectionHeader.label.text = "Entertainment Radio"
            return sectionHeader
        case 3:
            sectionHeader.label.text = "Religious Radio"
            return sectionHeader
        default:
            sectionHeader.label.text = "Section Header Issue"
            return sectionHeader
        }
    } else {
        print("section header issue")
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MediaCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionViewCell
    
    let station = stations[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = station.name
    cell.imageView.image = stationImages[station.name]
    
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Its here where I'd like to get the position of the station and pass it to the mediaVC

    let station = stations[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    mediaVC.station = station
    present(mediaVC, animated: true)
    
}

func parseJSON(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(StationData.self, from: data)
        let newsData = decodedData.stations
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.stations.append(newsData.filter { $0.category == "News" && $0.medium == "TV"})
            self.stations.append(newsData.filter { $0.medium == "Radio" && $0.category == "News"})
            self.stations.append(newsData.filter { $0.medium == "Radio" && $0.category == "Entertainment"})
            self.stations.append(newsData.filter { $0.medium == "Radio" && $0.category == "Religious"})
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

        print("all stations loaded successfully")
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding: \(error)")
    }
}
}

// MediaVC 

import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class MediaPlayerVC: UIViewController {

public var position: Int = 0
public var stations = [[Station]]()

public var station: Station?
var player: AVPlayer?
var isPlaying: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
    configure()

}


func configure() {
    
    guard let station = station else { return }
    
    let urlString = station.streamURL

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("url issue")
            return
        }

        player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        guard let player = player else {
            print("player issue")
            return
        }
        player.volume = 0.5

        player.play()

    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
  
    nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}

// This is where I need to implement "position" somehow
@objc func nextButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    if position < stations.count - 1 {
        position = position + 1
        player?.pause()
        for subview in view.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}

@objc func backButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    if position > 0 {
        position = position - 1
        player?.pause()
        for subview in view.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: "Its here where I'd like to get the position of the station" ??? You seem to be successfully getting the station, right? And you know perfectly well where it is in the array of arrays; it is at `[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`. So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @matt If I dont want the next/previous buttons, then I can just dismiss the mediaVC and tap on another station for the mediaVC to reappear and play that station, which is what I think you're describing. However, I'd like to include a next/previous button in the mediaVC to avoid having to leave the mediaVC to change stations. To do so, I have to pass the array and the currently (initially) playing stations position to the mediaVC for the next/previous button to access. When I do so, the indexing breaks once I access a station from a different indexPath.section for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: Why not use an `IndexPath`?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you once again for solving it. I passed IndexPath over to mediaVC and was able to index with position.section and position.row. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you necessarily need an `Int`.  You just need a single-value index for an array of arrays, that you can more or less treat like an `Int` which means rolling your own.

I think this will give you what you need:

```swift
extension Array where Element: RandomAccessCollection, Element.Index == Int
{
    struct DoubleIndex: Comparable, Strideable
    {
        let collection: [Element]
        let outerIndex: Int
        let innerIndex: Int
        
        public func advanced(by n: Int) -> DoubleIndex
        {
            precondition(outerIndex < collection.endIndex)
            precondition(innerIndex < collection[outerIndex].endIndex)
            
            if n == 0 { return self }
            if n > 0
            {
                if innerIndex + n >= collection[outerIndex].endIndex
                {
                    return DoubleIndex(
                        collection: collection,
                        outerIndex: outerIndex + 1,
                        innerIndex: collection[outerIndex + 1].startIndex
                    ).advanced(by: n - (collection[outerIndex].endIndex - innerIndex))
                }
                
                return DoubleIndex(
                    collection: collection,
                    outerIndex: outerIndex,
                    innerIndex: innerIndex + n
                )
            }
            
            if innerIndex + n < collection[outerIndex].startIndex
            {
                return DoubleIndex(
                    collection: collection,
                    outerIndex: outerIndex - 1,
                    innerIndex: collection[outerIndex - 1].endIndex - 1
                ).advanced(by: n + (innerIndex - collection[outerIndex].startIndex))
            }
            
            return DoubleIndex(
                collection: collection,
                outerIndex: outerIndex,
                innerIndex: innerIndex + n
            )
        }
        
        // Comparable conformance
        static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
        {
            return lhs.outerIndex == rhs.outerIndex
                && lhs.innerIndex == lhs.innerIndex
        }
        
        static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
        {
            return lhs.outerIndex < rhs.outerIndex
                || (lhs.outerIndex == rhs.outerIndex && lhs.innerIndex < rhs.innerIndex)
        }
        
        // Strideable Conformance
        func distance(to other: Array<Element>.DoubleIndex) -> Int
        {
            if other < self { return -other.distance(to: self) }
            
            if outerIndex == other.outerIndex {
                return other.innerIndex - innerIndex
            }
            
            return collection[outerIndex].endIndex - innerIndex
                + DoubleIndex(
                    collection: collection,
                    outerIndex: outerIndex + 1,
                    innerIndex: collection[outerIndex].startIndex
                ).distance(to: other)
        }
        
    }
    
    var doubleStartIndex: DoubleIndex
    {
        DoubleIndex(
            collection: self,
            outerIndex: startIndex,
            innerIndex: self[startIndex].startIndex
        )
    }
    
    var doubleEndIndex: DoubleIndex {
        DoubleIndex(collection: self, outerIndex: endIndex, innerIndex: 0)
    }
    
    var doubleIndices: Range<DoubleIndex> { doubleStartIndex..<doubleEndIndex }
    
    subscript(index: DoubleIndex) -> Element.Element {
        self[index.outerIndex][index.innerIndex]
    }
}

extension Array
    where Element: MutableCollection,
          Element: RandomAccessCollection,
          Element.Index == Int
{
    subscript(index: DoubleIndex) -> Element.Element
    {
        get { self[index.outerIndex][index.innerIndex] }
        set { self[index.outerIndex][index.innerIndex] = newValue }
    }
}
```

So you can iterate over the whole array like this:

```swift
for i in stations.doubleIndices {
   doSomethingWithAStation(stations[i]
}
```

In general you can advance the index by

```swift
doubleIndex = doubleIndex.advanced(by: 1)
```

Keep in mind that if you mutate the either the outer or inner arrays, this implementation of `DoubleIndex` will continue to refer to the array as it was when it was created.  For that reason you probably should not include the second extension that conforms to `MutableCollection`.  It's fine to use a DoubleIndex to mutate the collection so long as you're either doing one-for-one replacement, so the arrays dimensions don't change, but it will trigger copy-on-write since the index has a copy of the array so it can figure out where it is.  `append` and `remove` will definitely invalidate the `DoubleIndex`.

Comment: Hi Chip, Thanks for giving this some thought. Another user suggested I use IndexPath and it seems like a simpler implementation but I really appreciate the time and write up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want something that increases or decreases an index path that describes an array-of-arrays. This will do it, provided none of the arrays is empty (I didn't bother to check for that, sorry):

```
extension IndexPath {
    func inc<T>(against arr:[[T]]) -> IndexPath? {
        let ip = self
        let sub = arr[ip.section]
        if ip.section + 1 == arr.count && ip.item == arr[ip.section].count {
            return nil
        }
        var item = ip.item + 1
        if ip.item == arr[ip.section].count {
            return IndexPath(item: 0, section: ip.section + 1)
        }
        return IndexPath(item: ip.item + 1, section: ip.section)
    }
    func dec<T>(against arr:[[T]]) -> IndexPath? {
        let ip = self
        let sub = arr[ip.section]
        if ip.section == 0 && ip.item == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        var item = ip.item - 1
        if ip.item == 0 {
            return IndexPath(item: arr[ip.section-1].count, section: ip.section - 1)
        }
        return IndexPath(item: ip.item - 1, section: ip.section)
    }
}
```

And here's a test; try it in a playground:

```
let ip = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 1)
let arr = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

var result = ip.dec(against: arr)
result = result!.dec(against: arr)
result = result!.dec(against: arr)
result = result!.dec(against: arr)
result = result!.dec(against: arr)
result = result!.dec(against: arr)

result = ip.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
result = result!.inc(against: arr)
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for giving this some thought. I need to practice with generics so I'll definitely give this a go. Another user suggested I use IndexPath and it seems like a simpler implementation.

Comment: I _am_ showing you how to use IndexPath. The generic is irrelevant (not even sure what I was thinking with that part).